# How to move specific objects to the beginning of a list using java 8 Stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider this list of String

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("c", "k", "f", "e", "k", "d");
```

What i want to do is to move all `k` Strings to the beginning of the `list` and keep the rest at the same order.

What i have tried so far (it is working but i think it is so ugly)

```
list = Stream.concat(list.stream().filter(s -> s.equals("k")),
        list.stream().filter(s -> !s.equals("k"))).collect(
        Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

list.stream().forEach(System.out::print);
```

Output:

```
kkcfed
```

I am asking if there is another Stream features which i don't know to help me solve the problem more efficiently.

Comment: Do you want to create new list with that order or can we reorder your original list?

Comment: I hope if we reorder the same list

Comment: Than `assylias` provided you proper solution. You can simplify it a little with `sort(...)` instead of `stream().sorterd(...)` like `list.sort((s1, s2) -> "k".equals(s1) ? -1 : "k".equals(s2) ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: Yes, it is simplier but i just wanted a way using Stream (for better learning of java 8 features) @Pshemo

Comment: This is a problem which can be equally solved, and better so, without streams

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a custom comparator:

```
list.stream()
        .sorted((s1, s2) -> "k".equals(s1) ? -1 : "k".equals(s2) ? 1 : 0)
        .forEach(System.out::print);
```

For better readability you could also extract it in a separate method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList("c", "k", "f", "e", "k", "d");
  list.stream()
          .sorted(kFirst())
          .forEach(System.out::print);
}

private static Comparator<? super String> kFirst() {
  return (s1, s2) -> "k".equals(s1) ? -1 : "k".equals(s2) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, but this hardly seems an appropriate use of streams.  Sorting is `O(nlogn)` and this should be solvable in `O(n)`.